# Uploading 2 files with same name to FTP using powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am a beginner at powershell script and I am stuck
I am trying to upload 2 xml files with the same name to FTP, but I am getting the following error

> ```
>  Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An
> exception occurred during a WebClient request." At
> C:\powershell\ExternalWidgets\upload-to-ftp.ps1:51 char:16
> +                $webclient.UploadFile($uri.AbsoluteUri, $LocalPath)
> +                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException`
> ```

Here is the script:

```
#SET CREDENTIALS
$credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $pass)


cd $target
$DirectoryContent = Get-ChildItem -Directory

foreach($item in $DirectoryContent){

  cd $item

  $currentFolderItems = Get-ChildItem 
        
foreach( $subfolderItem in $currentFolderItems)
{
    
    if ($subfolderItem.name -eq "package.json") {
        $subItem = Get-ChildItem -Directory
            
        foreach($subItem in $subItem)
        {
            
            
            if ($subItem.name -eq "coverage") {
                $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $subItem
                
                $n = 0
                foreach ($file in $files) 
                {  
                
                    #rename coverage file
                    if($file.Name -eq "cobertura-coverage.xml") {
                    
                       $newFileName=$file.Name.Replace("cobertura-coverage.xml","cobertura-coverage$n.xml")   
                       Rename-Item $file -NewName $newFileName
                       $newFileName
                    }
                    $n++
                }
            
            }
            
        }
           
        
        $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
        $webclient.Credentials = New-Object 
        System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass) 

        $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp + "/" + $folder)
           
        #Delete files from FTP
        # $fileUploaded =($uri + "\" + $newFileName)
        # $fileUploaded
        # Remove-Item $fileUploaded  
        
        $LocalPath =($target + "\" + $item + "\" + "coverage" + "\" + 
        $newFileName).Replace(".\", "").Replace('\', '/')  
    
        $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $LocalPath)
    
       
        
      #cd.. 
    }
    
       
}
       
       
cd ..
```

}

I also get an error when I want to rename one of the files. What step am I missing? Thank you

Comment: What values are output for `$LocalPath` and `$uri.AbsoluteUri` before the error occurs?  What error is thrown when renaming the file(s)?  Also, the version-specific tags are for help with...that specific version; typically you'd choose (at most) one, that being the version you're actually using.

Comment: $LocalPath output is the path to the local file, but with only the extension of the file, not the file name and $uri.AbsoluteUri output is the path to the folder where I want the file to be uploaded. The error after renaming the file is : Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'C:\ExternalWidgets\Source\s\appointment-widget\coverage\cobertura-coverage.xml' does not exist.